# How do I change number of windows backup copies?

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup

([That](https://serverfault.com/questions/450682/keep-certain-number-of-backups-with-windows-server-backup) was unclear)

So I've set up a standard daily windows backup (≈10 GB of files) on a 1 TB hard drive and it only makes two copies, and I want 30 or 60. How do I change that?

I just don't know, I couldn't find any info about it...

Answer (score 2):

The built in Windows Backup will take a full and then incrementals using VSS then overwriting the oldest when space becomes an issue automatically...so I'm not sure if you just haven't waited long enough after setting it up or you set up something odd.

Follow the official Technet Article and the links there for setting up your backup on your server:

[Backing Up Your Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/404a51b5-99a6-43d1-b5a5-36261cb5ade2)

That should get you going just fine.